# In Ruby on Rails, why will story.votes return an empty Array object, but story.votes.create will actually invoke a method of the Vote class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

In Ruby on Rails, say a Story object can "has_many" Vote objects  (a story is voted "hot" by many users).

So when we do a

```
s = Story.find(:first)
```

`s` is a Story object, and say

```
s.votes
```

returns `[]`
and

```
s.votes.class
```

returns `Array`

So clearly, s.votes is an empty Array object.

At this time, when

```
s.votes.create
```

is called, it actually invokes a method of the Vote class?  How come an Array class object can invoke a Vote class method?

Comment: It doesn't directly call the method on the `Vote` class - for starters the `Vote` will already be associated with the `Story`, something that wouldn't happen if you just called `Vote.create` with the same parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `.votes` is *not* returning an `Array`, it's returning a special `Association` object.

The reason it looks like an `Array` is because the association object delegates all of its methods except for the dynamic ones like `create` to an array object it holds internally. And, this means that when you call `.class` on the object, that **also** gets delegated to the Array object.

Comment: That's a better explanation of what I was attempting to describe.

Answer (score 1):

`votes` is not an array, it's a method of a `Story` object. If you call it alone, it returns an array of all `Vote` records associated with that `Story`. The reason you are given `Array` when you do `s.votes.class` is that `s.votes` is returning an array (which in this case is empty because `s` has no votes) and you're checking the class of the returned array.

In turn, `s.votes.create` is another method dynamically generated by Rails based on your model associations. It's not a method of `Array`.

Comment: Ruby can have this model association capability?  in other languages, i think even when s.votes is a method and when it returns an empty Array object, then s.votes.create is forced to be the same as [].create, i think

Comment: Ruby isn't magic enough to return one thing if you call a method 'bare', but then return something else if you're chaining more methods.